# Problems installing PyProFit

Tags: python, cmd, pip

I am trying to download PyProFit, which is a Galaxy-image fitting module from https://github.com/ICRAR/pyprofit. When I enter

```
pip install pyprofit
```

on CMD or Canopy (python) comman prompt then I get error message saying:

```
No C/C++ compiler with C++11 support found. Use the CC environment variable to specify a different compiler if you have
```

Can any one help me fixing this problem or guide me through the installation please?